# How to make video responsive for all the screen sizes?

Tags: css, html

First of all, the video is kinda scaled and I'd love it to fit in the whole screen. Besides that, I can't figure out how to make video responsive on all screen sizes.

**HTML**

```
<div class="spread-video">
  <video src="https://b922bde52f23a8481830-83cb7d8d544f653b52d1a1621f05ea9d.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/video/landingpage.mp4" autoplay="" loop="">
  </video>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.spread-video {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Does anybody know how to achieve this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: If the video is a different aspect ratio than the screen, then you are going to introduce cropping in one way or another.

Comment: @Quantastical can I make it look smaller using CSS?

Comment: http://embedresponsively.com/ You can adapt the code for youtube embed to work with the video tag.

Comment: I added Codepen sandbox for playing around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target the `<video>` instead of the parent div, see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m1pz6zcu/4/

```
.spread-video > video {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Since the aspect ratio of the video is different from that of the view port, a work around for the issue is to make the video width bigger then the viewport width, center it and hide the overflow. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m1pz6zcu/6/

```
.spread-video > video {
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -50%;
}
.spread-video{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: On larger displays I can see the gap at the bottom. It seems that height isn't responsive. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You could also use a height:100% in there but you'll then get black bars on each side of the video as it tries to maintain it's aspect ratio.

Comment: @BillyLogan the only other option is to make the video larger then the veiwport, because the aspect ratio of the video will all ways stay the same.

Comment: @BillyLogan see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/m1pz6zcu/5/ I set the video to 150% width and moved it to the left -25% to center it.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith This workaround is suitable enough for me as I don't have skills in video editing. Thank you so much. I will keep in mind that I need video with the same aspect ratio as the screen for the next time. Could you provide this in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following css

```
.spread-video video {
  width:100%;  
}
```

Comment: On larger displays I can see the gap at the bottom. Is there any way to fix this? It seems that height isn't responsive.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/mlegg10/fsftz8rt/4/

```css
/* Flexible iFrame */

.flexible-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flexible-container iframe,
.flexible-container object,
.flexible-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Responsive iFrame -->
<div class="flexible-container">
<iframe src="https://b922bde52f23a8481830-83cb7d8d544f653b52d1a1621f05ea9d.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/video/landingpage.mp4" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
position: relative;

padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 Aspect Ratio */

padding-top: 25px;
```

or this one

```
position: absolute;

width: 100%!important;

height: 100%!important;
```